# Flask, FastCGI and 500 HTTP status because of warning

Tags: python-3.x, iis, fastcgi, windows-server-2012-r2

Python flask app with 4 endpoints, 3 of them works fine.
Main one, that handles GraphQL query crushes with 500 Internal server error.
The application works on IIS 8.5 with wfastcgi.py module.
IIS error handler shows this stack:

```
Warning — MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
ModuleName — FastCgiModule 
Notification — EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
HttpStatus — 500 
HttpReason — INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 
HttpSubStatus — 0 
ErrorCode — The operation completed successfully. (0x0) 
ConfigExceptionInfo
```

I launched source on flask dev server, and GraphQL handler is working as it used to be.
Founded some solutions about disabling in IIS config Custom Error — not working for me.

By the way, requests on this endpoint, that must cause client errors ( bad request, UNAUTHORIZED, forbidden ) resolves as they used to be.

Comment: "The operation completed successfully. (0x0)" indicates that IIS (FastCGI) works flawlessly, and the issue comes from either wfastcgi.py or your Flask app. Use Linux to host such please, as Microsoft no longer supports wfastcgi.py as it did.

Comment: you could try to set this code in web.config file:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
`<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>` and restart the site.